# Git Push a different local branch to master branch in Github

Tags: git, github, push, branch, pull-request

I have a Local Project.Now my master branch in github and my master branch are completely different.Now I want to push my new branch named "fms_gres" which I am currently working on to my master branch in Github. But when i use push command in git bash it is telling me to integrate my changes.I didn't understand that.So I created a branch in my github repo called "fms_gres" and pushed my local branch to my github branch.But when I want to make a pull request and merge my Github "fms_gres" to my github master branch , I couldn't make it since it's saying they have unrelated histories. Even If i could clear my entire master branch in Github and make it empty I'm fine with it. So I'm stuck here.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge fms_gres
git push -f origin master
```

By doing the above way, you are merging your local branch in `master` locally and then pushing the `master` branch

You should follow the below steps for git/code:

1. git checkout master
2. git pull origin master
3. git checkout -b "task_name"
4. Make the changes in the new branch
5. git add .  # if you want to add all files otherwise add one by one like git add fileone filetwo...
6. git commit -m "commit message"
7. git push origin "task_name" #new branch
8. Create a pull request
9. Review the code
   10.Merge in master if all looks good.